# why this output in java program print value 300

Tags: java

I have following java program,

```
class A{
    int a=100;

    A(int i){

    }
    {
        a=300;
    }
    void printA(){
        System.out.println("a : "+a);
    }

}
class Demo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        A a1=new A(200);
        a1.printA();  //300
    }
}
```

but I cant understand why main method 'a1.printA(); ' as 300 can you explain some thing?

Comment: Because you don't assign `i` to `a` in your constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class A{
    A(int i){

    }
    int a=100;
    {
        a=300;
    }
    void printA(){
        System.out.println("a : "+a);
    }

}
class Demo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        A a1=new A(200);
        a1.printA();  //300
    }
}
```

OK, you set the value for that instance variable two times:

```
int a = 100;
```

this is the first one to execute. So, this is where it starts.

Then, you initialize your class, so your initialize block will be executed, which contains:

```
a=300;
```

this will overwrite the previous value.

You also pass a param to your constructor, but you don't use it. So this doesn't change the value of a.

Comment: how could I use constructor parameter values 200

Comment: @sinsen526 check the other posted answer for this.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't print the value `200` (as you'd expect), because you never assign the value of `a` in your constructor.

If you change your constructor to:

```
A (int i) {
    this.a = i;
}
```

Then the output is `200`.

What you have written there:

```
{
    a = 300;
}
```

Is just an execution block, that gets executed when the class is loaded.